# How to provide an own UIWindow subclass as the main window in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

For inspecting all events posted to the views of the window, I want to make a subclass of `UIWindow` and make that `-keyAndVisible` in the app delegate.

However, my project already came with an nasty `MainWindow.xib` file ;-) so I find it hard to do that now, since that nib guy is creating the window. Is there any way I can get rid of this `MainWindow.xib`? Or is there another way to have an subclass of `UIWindow` in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete MainWindow.xib remove refrences from info.plist and your app delegate. Then you can create an instance of your custom window in the app delegate and call `keyAndVisible` like the app delegate currently does.

Answer (score 7):

Or in Interface Builder you can change the Window's class from UIWindow to your subclass in MainWindow.xib (using the Identity Inspector).